# Gwibber super strange interface

Tags: 12.04, gwibber

if I run gwibber from terminal like below:

```
 candy@candy-bane:~$ gwibber
(gwibber:3695): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_radio_button_set_group: assertion `!g_slist_find (group, radio_button)' failed

(gwibber:3695): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Loading plugin for twitter
Loading plugin for facebook
Loading plugin for identica
```

then the result of my gwibber is:

[image: Selection 001]

Update and use this social media built-in toy, or suggest me a good one?

Answer (score 0):

As OP wanted , I came up with alternatives

- [Polly](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/twitter-app-polly-adds-ubuntu-12-10-support)

  ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:conscioususer/polly-unstable

   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install polly
  ```

Its supports [all version of Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~conscioususer/+archive/polly-unstable).

- [Friends-app](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/install-friends-app-gwibber-rewritten.html)

  you can install it directly from your terminal with

  ```
   sudo apt-get install friends-app
  ```

hope that helps.